# Spring integration outbound email

Tags: spring-integration, email

I want to implement email functionality using spring integration

How to do this ?
I have gone through some links but not useful
sample link
http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-integration-hands?page=0,3

Please do the needful

Answer (score 2):

See [the Spring Integration Mail documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html).

Take a look at the [test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mail/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/config/mailOutboundChannelAdapterParserTests.xml) for configuration examples.

Also, [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/dsl/si4demo/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/si4demo/springone/f/FMail.java#L87) shows how to do it with the new Java DSL.